# Adding Fractions

Tags: c++

I am making a method to add two fractions of any type, that is integer, radical, etc. This is what I have so far. If the numerator and denominator of both fraction are integers, then its easy to do. But if it is radical or any other complex numbers, I have to change my code. So my question is How do I check if the parameter (numerator and denominator of the fraction) is an integer or radical or pi etc? Number class is the superclass and Fraction class is the subclass.

```
string Fraction::add(Number n)
{
 Number newNumerator1 = n.denominator * numerator;
 Number newNumerator2 = denominator * n.numerator;
 Number newNum = newNumerator1 + newNumerator2;
 Number newDenominator = denominator * n.denominator;

 ostringstream a;
 a << newNum << "/" << newDenominator << endl;
 cout << a.str();
 return a.str();
}
```

Comment: this is tagged java and c++... which one is it? what `number` class are you using? where are all these other variables coming from? theres not enough code here to answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `Fraction n` instead of a `Number n`?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you add a `Fraction n` instead of a `Number n`? Since you use `Number`, this doesn't make any sense to the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to do this symbolically (thereby preserving any radicals or other signs) you need to rework your code to work more like Mathematica or Maple, which would manipulate the fractions on a purely symbolic level. The numerators and denominators can't be simple data types like `int` or `double`. Instead, you will probably have to design a custom template that allows you to define complex quantities, like the numerator and denominator below:

(4 + √5i)   ÷   (√3 - 3^√4)

This is a very complex system to implement, and probably way beyond the scope of what you wish to accomplish. If you're simply looking to evaluate the addition of the passed fractions, then force the parameters to be simple fractions, or create overloaded functions for different parameters.